# Button CSS issue

Tags: css, firefox

I have one button , over that I am applying below style/class. but this class doesn't work properly in mozila browser. it works in IE. Button's starting point I have icon which renders at the middle of left side and text comes beside that. 
IE renders in middle but mozila renders at top of ![enter image description here][1]button. please let me know what I m doing wrong here.  also find attached screenshot of the issue

```
.class
{         
        padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background:url(GB_Link.gif) no-repeat 0px -2px;
    display:inline-block;
    height:20px;
    line-height:13px;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Verdana, Sans-Serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align:left;
    text-indent:25px;
    text-color:black;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:180px;
    cursor:hand;
    border: 1px solid #77A2B5;
}
```

Comment: If we cannot have the background image, what is its size? Also, the screen-cap is missing.

Answer (score 0):

this is a general issues.
add the following code at the top of the layout or in your html page where you have defined the html tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

I hope so your problem will be short out.
I think you have understood very well.

Answer (score 0):

Set the line-height to the same as the button height:

```
line-height: 20px;
```